# Remove Feature (Footer) in MAF

Tags: oracle-maf

I want to remove feature in MAF screen as mention in attached image.

I have many tried to remove marked area in attached screenshots. Is is possible to remove ?

Thanks in advance.

[Remove Makred Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHTpX.gif)

Answer (score 0):

MAF lets you choose what feature(s) you want to show (or hide) in the navigation bar. You can also specify if you (don't) want your app to display a navigation bar.

All this is done in **maf-application.xml** in the sections *"Registered Features"* and *"Navigation"*